# image filters for iphone sdk development

Tags: iphone, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am planning to develop an iphone app which makes use of image filters like blurring, sharpening,etc. I noticed that there are few approaches for this one,

1. Use openGL ES. I even found an example code on apple iphone dev site. How easy is openGL for somebody who has never used it? Can the image filters be implemented using the openGL framework?
2. There is a Quartz demo as well posted on apple iphone dev site. Has anybody used this framework for doing image processing? How is this approach compared to openGL framework?
3. Don't use openGL and Quartz framework. Basically access the raw pixels from the image and do the manipulation myself.
4. Make use of any custom built image processing libraries like [this](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/) one. Do you know of any other libraries like this one?

Can anybody provide insights/suggestions on which option is the best? Your opinions are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz doesn't have access to Core Image yet on the iPhoneOS so you can't use the Core Image filters like you do on MacOS.

I would go with a dedicated library. There's a lot of overhead in OpenGL ES you don't want to miss with if you're not using it for anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another alternative for image filtering. They provide lots of filters using core image framework.

http://www.binpress.com/app/photo-effects-sdk-for-ios/801

Answer (score 0):

If your App has a support of iOS6 the use CoreGraphics and CoreImage. It contains many filters and some other approaches through which yo get other composite filters.

If you r not on iOS6 the you can use GPUImage framwork  or ImageMagick.

and the last option is to manipulating pixels values, but it needs an filter algorithm to add filters on Image